# UICollectionViewCell gets ambiguous height from custom cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uistoryboard

I made a very simple `UICollectionView` with a custom `UICollectionViewCell` using Interface Builder. I made a project on [GitHub](https://github.com/Hapeki/UICollectionViewExample) so you can reproduce the issue. The `UICollectionView` works fine on the simulator but Xcode keeps reporting the error:

> "DefaultCell expected: Height = 34, Actual: Height = 150".

The suggested solutions from Interface Builder don't fix the error. The issue sometimes disappears when I change the classname of the UICollectionViewCell to something else, however this is only temporary. No other errors are shown in the View Inspector or in the developer console. Adding labels or images to the cell becomes difficult since Interface Builder doesn't know the right size for the cell.

See the image below for the error.

[image]

Comment: I opened your project multiple times without getting the error. And yes, adding labels and images to a collectionviewcell and setting the layout afterwards is not very easy

Comment: @J.Doe that's odd, I cloned the project from GitHub just now and I did receive the error .. see the edited question above.  Could this be related to user preferences? Weird.

Comment: I too have tried opening your project, running on different simulators but I am not receiving any error.

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu that's very odd, what happens if you open the storyboard and add a label to the cell?

Comment: @Hapeki yes I got the same error, But whats mysterious about it is that when I selected cell and in the side pain in collection view cell just increased the cell's width by 1, the error disappeared and then again I set it 150 but no error was shown. This might help you.

Comment: and make sure that you select custom in cell size in the sidebar in the storyboard.Hope this helps u!

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu this seems to work, thank you. I think it's a bug in interface builder because I have to keep applying the "reset width trick" everytime I get this warning. Could you write down your answer in a comment so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163203/discussion-between-pallavi-srikhakollu-and-hapeki).

Comment: @Hapeki I am glad that it worked, I posted the same comment as an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I downloaded your project from GitHub and found out the issue.  But what is mysterious about it is that when I selected cell and in the side panel in collection view cell just increased the cell's width by 1, the error disappeared and then again I set it 150 but no error was shown.Also, make sure that you select custom in cell size in the sidebar in the storyboard.I think its an interface builder bug. Hope this works. Cheers!